# Insert a booking only if not already taken in a SQLite Database

Tags: database, sqlite

Lets consider the following database

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resources (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, , name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookings (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  resource_id INT, 
  start_date DATETIME, 
  end_date DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY(resource_id) REFERENCES resources(id)
);

INSERT INTO resources (name) VALUES ("Meeting Room Marie Curie")
```

I would like to create a new 'booking' for a specified 'resource', only if there is not a booking already created for that resource.

I have tried the following request but it keeps create a booking anyway. I think there is something wrong with the condition in the second SELECT statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO bookings(resource_id, start_date, end_date) 
    SELECT 1, "2020-06-02T19:00:00", "2020-06-02T20:00:00"
EXCEPT
    SELECT id, start_date, end_date FROM bookings
        WHERE 
          resource_id = 1 
          AND ( "2020-06-02T19:00:00" >= end_date OR "2020-06-02T20:00:00" <= start_date ) = 1
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that you could do is define the column `resource_id` to be unique:

```
resource_id INT UNIQUE
```

so there is no case of duplicates.
Then use `INSERT OR IGNORE`:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO bookings(resource_id, start_date, end_date) 
SELECT 1, "2020-06-02T19:00:00", "2020-06-02T20:00:00"
```

If there is already a row in `bookings` with `resource_id = 1` then nothing will be inserted because of the unique constraint.

If you can't change the table then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO bookings(resource_id, start_date, end_date) 
SELECT 1, "2020-06-02T19:00:00", "2020-06-02T20:00:00"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE resource_id = 1)
```

In your code there is also this condition:

```
AND ("2020-06-02T19:00:00" >= end_date OR "2020-06-02T20:00:00" <= start_date) = 1
```

You can include it in the last query:

```
INSERT INTO bookings(resource_id, start_date, end_date) 
SELECT 1, "2020-06-02T19:00:00", "2020-06-02T20:00:00"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM bookings 
  WHERE resource_id = 1
  AND ("2020-06-02T19:00:00" >= end_date OR "2020-06-02T20:00:00" <= start_date)
)
```

No need for `...= 1`

Comment: I see, the NOT EXISTS statement seem to be a more elegant way to handle conditions in SQLite. Anyway it seems to work has expected, thanks a lot for your help !